# Force torque sensor - ROS Noetic

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-noetic, force

I want to simulate a force torque sensor located at the tip of robot arm. Does anyone have a working example or a tutorial for ROS Noetic?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user1214542, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: There's a [tutorial here](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=force_torque_sensor&cat=sensors) on how to add force torque sensors to Gazebo. Did you try these steps? Did you get an error or is there some other reason you believe there is a problem? Please *edit your question* to include details of the specific problem you're having and the steps you've taken so far to troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried this [link](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=force_torque_sensor&cat=sensors) and it's working fine. But I don't know how can I implement this for robotic arm?

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully followed [the tutorial](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=force_torque_sensor&cat=sensors) to implement the force torque sensor and you just want to attach it to the end of a robotic arm, then go to where the joint is defined

```
<joint name="joint_01" type="revolute">
```

change the parent tag

```
<parent>world</parent>
```

to point to the end link on your robot.